# PyQGIS CRS on the fly reprojetion

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

As a first step of a pyqgis plugin I'm trying to import several shape files at once. To get them aligned, using the GUI, I'd enable on the fly reprojections and set the project crs to WGS84. I'd then set the layer CRS to WGS84 for each layer resulting in all layers being in the same layer extent.

The following code tries to replicate the GUI steps. However, the end result is that there is still no overlay between the layers, unlike when I do the steps via GUI. What am I missing out?

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True) # Enable on the fly reprojections
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId)) # Set project coordinate reference system to WGS84

for path, name in ShapeFileList:
    vector = QgsVectorLayer(path, name, "ogr")
    if not vector.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
    vector.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId)) # Set layer coordinate reference system to WGS84
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vector)
```

Comment: What's the source of the vector layers? Are you sure the input data is in WGS84 CRS? Always? Are you aware that setting the layer CRS does NOT reproject the layers? Shapefiles usually come with projection information in the .prj file and it should not be necessary to set the layer CRS manually.

Comment: I am aware that not all the input data is WGS84. The layers are all either OSGB36 or WGS84. I was, however, not aware that setting layer CRS does not reproject them.
Essentially what I tried to reproduce is what I have to do using the GUI to get them in the same system:
Settings > Project Properties > Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation + set it to WGS84.
Then Set Layer CRS > set it to WGS84.
These steps work when using the GUI ... the code just tries to replicate that.

If there is a better way to get them into the same system I would be glad if you pointed me in a direction.

Comment: If the Shapefiles include correct .prj files, you should not change the layer CRS at all. Just enable on the fly reprojection for the project.

Comment: The shapefiles include .prj files. However, when I enable on the fly reprojection alone it is not working.

Comment: I just tested using two Shapefiles with different CRS and  setProjectionsEnabled(True) and it worked. Seems like some Shapefile .prj are not interpreted correctly. You have to sort that out. It's not a programming problem.

Comment: If someone googles this: my problem was that one shape file did have the wrong CRS, the others had the correct one leading to problems with the above code. The solution was calling setCrs only for the broken shapefile.
Again thank you, underdark.

Comment: @Thomas If you have found a solution to your problem you should post it as an answer to the question, rather than just a comment.