# QGIS Python - Convert the CRS of an in memory vector layer

Tags: qgis, python

In a python script of qgis I load layers from different datasources using the QgsVectorLayer() and  the QgsRasterLayer() commands. The coordinate reference systems of the data sources differs. Since I have for some sources only the permission to read, I cannot transfrom the CRS of the datasource. Thus, i have to change the CRS from old CRS into new CRS in the in memory layer. What is the way to do it, e.g. to get an extent() in the new coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

```
sourceCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(...source crs code...)

destCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(...dest crs code...)

xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(sourceCrs, destCrs) #you can also do reverse convertion

if geom.transform(xform):
   ...your code...
```

where geom is the QgsGeometry you want to transform... in your case a geometry created from the extent coordinate using static method of QgsGeometry:

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html

Regards

Comment: ok, i understand how to convert a single geometry.  Is this also the approach to convert a complete layer, i.e. to iterate over each geometry and transform it as you described? I am looking for doing in python something similar as the "on-the-fly" reprojection process in the qgis qui ...

Comment: i just fount that "ont-the-fly" reprojection can be done with setProjectionsEnabled(True) (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66767/pyqgis-crs-on-the-fly-reprojetion) and setCrsTransformEnabled in qgis 2.4.

Comment: to use less code probably is better to use some command interface by Procssing toolbox. All staffs you have in Processing can be accessed using python with:

Comment: import processing

processing.runalg("<alg name>",... parameters of the command)


I whould use gdal_translate to convert geometries and to get all processign parameters:

1) look for your command with: processing.alglist(<patter that can match your command>)
2) look for your command parameters with: processing.alghelp(<your command>)